# Triggering Celery Tasks from c++ with Redis

Tags: c++, django, asynchronous, redis, celery

We have a setup where we have a web frontend programmed in `Django` and a backend written in `C++` that parses data for us.
The frontend uses `Celery` in combination with `Redis` for asynchronous tasks.

Since it would be convenient in some situations, I was wondering today if it is possible to trigger a `Celery` task from within `C++`.

Since there is a `Redis` client available for `C++`, I am pretty sure that this is possible, if the correct messages are sent to `Redis`, however, I was not able to find any information on this anywhere.

My next step would be to try and dig the needed Information out of the `Celery` source code, but before I do that:

Does anybody have any information on this subject that could help me or get me started or is there even someone who has done this before?

Any help is appreciated. (Also if you got a reason why this will not work.)

Thank you.

Comment: With 'I was not able to find any information on this anywhere', what do you mean by 'this', exactly what messages to send to Redis? Inspecting the source code of the Django app should make that clear (I suppose the Django app sends off some stuff to a queue, a C++ program watches that queue and processes it, and the Django app receives the result).

Comment: by 'this' I mean the format of the messages or any information about the used messages. Of course this information should be available in the celery source, but before I dig into that I hoped that there would be a documentation somewhere that I simply wasn't able to find.

Comment: Tim, the underlying communication protocol that Redis uses is documented at http://redis.io/topics/protocol, it's not that complex (basically text over TCP/IP). There are a diversity of clients for many programming languages that will talk this protocol for you (http://redis.io/clients, but you probably already knew that). So, if you want to command Celery from a C++ program, you'd probably have to enter some message into a Redis instance from within that C++ program. The question is: what message exactly. If you know that, you can enter it either using TCP/IP or a Redis client library.

Comment: Yes, that is my question. I am aware that the information is available somewhere in the celery source but I was hoping that it was also documented somewhere else. Apparently that is not the case, so I'll start digging.

Comment: we trigger celery tasks from erlang. the message format is not fully documented - you have to read the celery source to understand the format - it is not too difficult to get working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar need to trigger a celery task from logstash.  Basically, I had to create a message that looked something like this:

```
{
    "body": "base_64_encoded_string (see below)",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "properties": {
        "body_encoding": "base64", 
        "correlation_id":"f009c9e0-0ca6-42a6-a046-3d0e53e06060",  
        "reply_to":"e1eb91f0-6780-4c34-b633-7ef9a46baf5e",
        "delivery_mode":2, 
        "delivery_tag": "7788b924-a7fe-4c9a-839e-1c7ca602dbba",
        "delivery_info": {
            "priority":0,
            "routing_key":"default",
            "exchange":"default"
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the decoded body translates to:

```
{
    "args": ["meta_val","doc_value"],
    "task":"goldstone.compliance.tasks.process_fim_event",
    "id":"23deb69e-49c1-4a61-8639-d4627d0fc591"
}
```

If you have kwargs on your task, you can add a `kwargs: {"key": "value", ...}` to your body.

The body above maps triggers a task called `process_fim_event`.  The task def looks like:

```
@task()
def process_fim_event(meta, doc):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this that I know of is to use [flower](https://github.com/mher/flower), a HTTP Celery API. With flower you can create a task with anything that can make an HTTP request. One example from the  Github Readme:
`$ curl -X POST -d '{"args":[1,2]}' http://localhost:5555/api/task/async-apply/tasks.add`

So, the idea is that your c++ app would make an HTTP request against the flower api, which would then insert the task into your Redis queue.

Comment: Ok, this would be a solution. However, I would prefer to use c++ directly as it seems to wast unnecessary resources to run another service for this.

Comment: Find out what kind of message is needed (possibly by inspecting the source of the Django app, which apparently already sends them), and use a C++ client library for Redis to send such a message. Then you won't need the intermediate steps of executing curl from your C++ program (or using curllib to do a HTTP request to your Redis instance).